# Is there a way to return literally nothing in python?

Tags: python

I'm learning python and I was just wondering if I there was a way to write a code that does something like:

```
def f(x):
    if x>1:
       return(x)
    else:
        # don't return anything
```

I'm asking about the else part of the code. I need to not return anything if `x<=1`, returning `None` isn't acceptable.

Comment: what would the calling code look like?

Comment: why dont you just return null?

Comment: When you just leave the function it is returning `None`, only way to avoid it is to throw exception or have non-terminating function.

Comment: Why is returning `None` unacceptable? You can ignore the return value of a function.

Comment: If you dont want to return anything , do not use the else statement. it works in python

Comment: @Kirca: You haven't said why `None` is unacceptable, but it's probably due to a misconception.  There's no way to end a function without either returning a value or raising an exception.

Comment: What do you want `var` to be bound to when you write `var = foo()` and the function is "returning literally nothing"?  You have to `raise` and add error handling to the caller.

Comment: Note that `return` isn't a function, so the parens around its argument are not needed and could be confusing.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There is no such thing as "returning nothing" in Python. Every function returns some value (unless it raises an exception). If no explicit `return` statement is used, Python treats it as returning `None`.

So, you need to think about what is most appropriate for your function. Either you should return `None` (or some other sentinel value) and add appropriate logic to your calling code to detect this, or you should raise an exception (which the calling code can catch, if it wants to).

Comment: +1 Although, could technically just "not return" (instead of `return None`) and it would be just as valid .. although it would offend my sensibilities.

Comment: `None`, `nothing`, `null`, and `nil` are used in programming languages to represent nothingness: https://nshipster.com/nil/. Meaning that returning `None` is the correct answer.

Answer (score 25):

To literally return 'nothing' use `pass`, which basically returns the value None if put in a function(Functions must return a value, so why not 'nothing'). You can do this explicitly and `return None` yourself though.

So either:

```
if x>1:
    return(x)
else:
    pass
```

or

```
if x>1:
    return(x)
else:
    return None
```

will do the trick.

Comment: Both of those examples are identical to having no `else` block at all.

Comment: Indeed, but why not have it there, for the sake of completeness.

Comment: "OP said returning None is not acceptable"  True, but that makes no sense, and OP hasn't explained what he meant.

Comment: `pass` doesn't "basically return the value `None`"; it literally doesn't do anything at all. The `None` return in that code example happens because control flow reaches the end of the function. `else: pass` is equivalent to omitting the `else` block in *every* case, i.e. even if there is more code after the complete `if` block.

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
def function(x):
     try:
         x = x+1
         return (x)
     except:
         return ('')
```

Comment: so this is the only thing that made sense on all these webpages for some reason. I don't really even want to return an empty string, but it works because I do not want to see `None` printed right now.

Comment: "but it works because I do not want to see None printed right now." Then there is an XY problem here, and the original question did not properly clarify the problem.

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing like returning nothing but what you are trying to do can be done by using an empty `return` statement. It returns a `None`.

You can see an example below:

```
if 'account' in command:
    account()

def account():
    talkToMe('We need to verify your identity for this. Please cooperate.')
    talkToMe('May I know your account number please?')
    acc_number = myCommand()
    talkToMe('you said your account number is '+acc_number+'. Is it right?')
    confirmation = myCommand()
    if confirmation!='yes' or 'correct' or 'yeah':
        talkToMe('Let\'s try again!')
        account()
    else:
        talkToMe('please wait!')
    return
```

This will return nothing to calling function but will stop the execution and reach to the calling function.

Comment: `if confirmation!='yes' or 'correct' or 'yeah':` does not do what you want it to do, and calling `account()` recursively to "restart" the function is ill-conceived.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel This is a snippet from a project I was working on. The code is correct with respect to the project and it answers the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> def f(x):
...    return x if x>1 else None
... 
>>> f(1),f(2)
(None, 2)
```

It will appear to 'return nothing':

```
>>> f(1)
>>>
```

But even the alternative returns None:

```
>>> def f2(x): 
...    if x>1: return x
... 
>>> f2(1),f2(2)
(None, 2)
```

Or:

```
>>> def f2(x):
...    if x>1: 
...        return x
...    else:
...        pass
... 
>>> f2(1),f2(2)
(None, 2)
```

So they are functionally the same no matter how you write it.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to all the answers, the only actual way to not return a function is to raise an exception. At least, as long as the program needs to run even after not returning anything.

So your code can be:

```
def f(x):
    if x>1:
        return x
    raise Exception
```

(Note that I didn't use an `else` block to raise the Exception since it would have already returned the value if the condition was satisfied. You could, however, do this in an `else` block, too)

On test running:

```
num1 = f(2)    # 2
num2 = f(0)    # Unbound; and error raised
```

Now this can be useful if you want to also keep returning `None` an option for some conditions, and not returning anything for some other conditions:

```
def f(x):
    if x > 0:
        return x
    elif x == 0:
        return None  # pass
    raise Exception

>>> num1 = f(1)  # 1
>>> num2 = f(0)  # None
>>> num3 = f(-1) # Unbound; and error raised
```

---

If you don't want the program to exit and show an error, you can make it catch the exception outside of the function:

```
try:
    num = f(0)
except:
    pass
```

This way, if at all `f(0)` raises an exception (which it would) it will be caught be the `except` block and you can happily continue the program, being rest assured that `num` is not `None`, but simply unbound.

---

**An interesting fact:**

The only other way to not return anything is probably to simply exit the program, which is what `exit()` and `quit()` do. When I check the return type for `exit()` and `quit()` in my code editor, it shows me `NoReturn`, which is different from when it shows `None` for a regular function :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above by others, it will always return None in your case. However you can replace it with white space if you don't want to return None type

```
def test(x):
    if x >1:
        return(x)
    else:
        return print('')
```

Comment: No need for the print() - just use return ''

Answer (score 1):

To get a blank result from return statement just type return "" . You will just a get a blank line in the end without anything printed on it

```
def f(x):
    if x>1:
       return(x)
    else:
        return ""
```

Comment: This was already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47583847/18145256).

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods and the former method returns `None` as explicitly stated in the latter:

```py
def fn1():
    pass

def fn2():
    return None

fn1() == fn2()
True
```

My personal preference is always for explicit methods, as it reduces mental overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda function with filter to return a list of values that pass if condition.

Example:

```
    myList = [1,20,5,50,6,7,2,100]
    result = list(filter(lambda a: a if a<10 else None, (item for item in myList)))
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
    [1,5,6,7,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have a tip for you !
Writing print(f(x)) will output None if there is no return value, but if you just call your function without the 'print', and instead write in the function some 'print(s)' you won't have a None value

Answer (score 0):

you can use
return `chr(0)`
cause `0` in `ASCII` doesn't have a character hence it leaves it blank

Answer (score 0):

In Simple Terms

```
for i in range(0,10):
    if i<5:
        None
    else:
       print("greater")
```

Output:-

```
greater
greater
greater
greater
greater
```

The code outputs nothing for all values less than 5.